# Using sshfs on Windows with system that required Kerberos authentication

Tags: windows, ssh, kerberos, remote-access, sshfs

So I was following [this](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/sshfs) tutorial to map a remote system as a network drive using sshfs. The issue is the remote system requires Kerberos authentication. So typically I have to do kinit before doing ssh user@remote but doing so before connecting through the network drive doesn't work for me. Is there any way to authenticate with Kerberos before I connect?

Comment: If the laptop is your own one, consider installing a Linux distribution on it like [Debian](https://debian.org/). It would be simpler.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you *cannot* use Kerberos with sshfs-win, because in normal mode it always waits for at least one password prompt, while in passwordless mode (sshfs.k) it always forces the authentication mechanism to 'publickey' when invoking the actual sshfs client, so there's no way to enable 'gssapi-with-mic' auth even if you do so via ~/.ssh/config.

For now I would suggest accessing the server via WinSCP; it supports Kerberos via Windows SSPI.

(On non-AD-member systems, use `cmdkey /add:*.example.com /user:foo@EXAMPLE.COM /pass` to store your Kerberos password in Windows Credential storage. This will allow any SSPI-based program to get tickets for the specified servers, including PuTTY, WinSCP, and even Win32-OpenSSH.)